# Not Getting desired output for android application

Tags: android

```
EditText numDisplay;
Button calculateNow;
int n=100;
int count=0;
List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    numDisplay= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    n= Integer.parseInt(numDisplay.toString());
    calculateNow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    calculateNow.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                boolean res = checkprime(primes, i);
                if (res) {
                    count++;
                    primes.add(i);
                }
            }
          numDisplay.setText( String.valueOf(count));
          // writer.write("total prime number till " + n + " is " + count);
        }});}

private static boolean checkprime(List<Integer> primes, int n) {
    int fence = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int prime : primes) {
        if (n % prime == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (prime >= fence)
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The output of program must print total number of prime numbers from 1 to 100.

I have used edit text to display total number of prime numbers when button is clicked.

But when I click button I don't get desired output.Any Help appreciated .
Thanx

Comment: "I don't get desired output": You need to explain in your question exactly what does happen and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I want to take input from user and print total number of prime number for the limit user has entered .From example user has entered 100 in edit text  output shown to user in edit text must be 25 total number of prime numbers

Comment: I enter 100 in first text box click the button android stops working.Error shown unfortunately android has stopped working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your as :-

```
public class AnimationActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText numDisplay;
Button calculateNow;
private int n;
int count=0;
List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    numDisplay= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    calculateNow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    calculateNow.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            n= Integer.parseInt(numDisplay.getText().toString());
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                boolean res = checkprime(primes, i);
                if (res) {
                    count++;
                    primes.add(i);
                }
            }
            numDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(count));

        }
    });}

private static boolean checkprime(List<Integer> primes, int n) {
    int fence = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int prime : primes) {
        if (n % prime == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (prime >= fence)
            break;
    }

    return true;
}}
```

Comment: You were retrieving value from edit text in onCreate(), you should do that after button click. And also you have declared int n=100; globally ,as your are taking input from user then no need to initialize it globally,